# How to create a transition without removal animation

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a .asymmetric transition that has an insertion animation but **doesn't have removal** one?

Something like:

```
AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .slide, removal: .none)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.identity` transition.

```swift
AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .slide, removal: .identity)
```